Ramification locus of a projection
I'm trying to write a code in magma (or sage) that given a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and a point on the surface, it give me the ramifiaction locus (so a quartic).
For writing the map I use "ProjectionFromNonsingularPoint(S,p)", but I don't know how to deal with the ramification locus.
I just started using magma so I apologize if this is supposed to be very easy.
Usefull part of the code:
//Creating the surface

F:=FiniteField(4);
P3<x,y,z,w> := ProjectiveSpace(F,3);
R:=CoordinateRing(P3);
d:=3;
f:=x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3;
S:=Scheme(P3,f);
Dimension(S), Degree(S), IsNonsingular(S);

//Counting the lines (Using patch of Grasmanians)
//In the first patch
A1<y11,y12,y21,y22>:=PolynomialRing(F,4);
M1:=Matrix([
[1,0,y11,y12],
[0,1,y21,y22]
]);
U1<u,v>:=PolynomialRing(A1,2);
uv:=Matrix([[u,v]]);
ll1:=Eltseq(uv*ChangeRing(M1,U1));
I1:=Ideal(Coefficients(Evaluate(f,ll1)));
X1:=Scheme(Spec(A1),I1);
Dimension(X1), Degree(X1), IsNonsingular(X1), IsReduced(X1);
#Points(X1);

//In the second patch
A2<y11,y12,y22>:=PolynomialRing(F,3);
M2:=Matrix([
[1,y11,0,y12],
[0,0,1,y22]
]);
U2<u,v>:=PolynomialRing(A2,2);
uv2:=Matrix([[u,v]]);
ll2:=Eltseq(uv2*ChangeRing(M2,U2));
I2:=Ideal(Coefficients(Evaluate(f,ll2)));
X2:=Scheme(Spec(A2),I2);
Dimension(X2), Degree(X2), IsNonsingular(X2), IsReduced(X2);
#Points(X2);
p:=S ! [0, 1, -1, 0];
Im, f, Imp:=ProjectionFromNonsingularPoint(S,p);
Dimension(Im);
Dimension(Imp);


Please include your code in your post. It's much easier to try to work with your example. That said, I'm not sure there's a built-in command to do this for surfaces. There is RamificationDivisor, but it looks like this is only for maps of curves.

@ViktorVaughn Thanks for the tip. Sorry it's the first time I ask something about a code. I edited the question!
